# DNF and YUM does not work after Purging usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/

Tags: python, bash, pip, fedora

I was fiddling around with Fedora, trying to uninstall a python Module. I couldn't find the one that I was looking for , so the half linux-primate brain thought of an Idea , to execute this.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

It did it's thing , and only after that I realized how stupid I was. DNF and YUM depends on it and whenever I execute DNF i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ImportError: No module named 'dnf'
```

And when I execute YUM

```
Redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf ' (see 'man yum2dnf')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ImportError: No module named 'dnf'
```

The only thing that Works is `yum-deprecated`. Everything else is in turmoil.

So how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purging the Site-Packages directory of Python3 removes a lot of the libraries that Fedora needs to function properly. This means tools like `dnf` and `yum` does not work.

These are the Steps that I took to fix this.

Step 1: Install `yum-deprecated`. Just type yum-deprecated on the terminal and it will ask do you want to install it. Type `y` and it will be installed.

Step 2: Run this Bash Command

```
rpm -qa | egrep "^python3" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' | xargs sudo yum-deprecated reinstall -y
```

This finds all the names of the Installed python 3 packages , and reinstall them.

Note to Myself: Never run commands like `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` ever again.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'rpm -Va' to identify the packages with missing files. You'll then have to download the matching RPM files from a Fedora mirror, and then use `rpm --reinstall` to fix those.

The higher-level dnf and yum packages rely on Python, so they're likely to just be broken. Fortunately, the lower-level rpm command doesn't, so if python packages are all you've removed, this should get you back in shape.

Comment: I did that and I piped the Output into this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-fWI8D4m3DxcWk0bmI3R1J5bGc/view?usp=sharing

Which is about 7000 lines. Not Particularly Useful.

Comment: Never Mind , Got it Working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You basically removed a lot of python files. A large portion of the system depends on the python, including `dnf` itself, which is written in python.

The best thing to do would be to back up all your files and reinstall system. If `yum-deprecated` still works, you might have the luck with reinstalling `dnf`:

```
yum-deprecated reinstall "dnf*"
```

but most probably you will need much more packages to take through the same procedure.

Comment: Didn't fix it. Can you give the names of Python packages that you have installed , as a requirement file.

Answer (score 1):

This can help.

`yum update python*`

`yum install dnf-data dnf-plugins-core libdnf-devel libdnf python2-dnf-plugin-migrate dnf-automatic`

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend who meet the same problem.

He tries to uninstall python3.7 in linux server by some amazing cmd `rpm -qa|grep python3|xargs rpm -ev --allmatches --nodeps` and  `whereis python3 |xargs rm -frv`.
This cause the `yum` and `dnf` broken.

Because we can not find `yum-deprecated`,so there are the following attempt.

I change the `/usr/bin/yum` to use a local python3.8 version, but it cause `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'` at last, and not solved it.

It is not a good way to  download many rpm packages in internet. And I can't use yum either. But I have another same os linux server, so I tried to copy the correlation files about python3.7.

```
$ rpm -ql python3-3.7.0-9.h4.eulerosv2r8.aarch64> py.log
$ while read -r line;do dirname $line |xargs -I {} ssh root@$remoteip "mkdir -p {}" ;scp $line root@$remoteip:$line  ;done<py.log

$ rpm -ql python3-libs-3.7.0-9.h4.eulerosv2r8.aarch64 >pylib.log
$ while read -r line;do dirname $line |xargs -I {} ssh root@$remoteip "mkdir -p {}" ;scp $line root@$remoteip:$line  ;done<pylib.log

scp -r /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages root@$remoteip:/usr/lib/python3.7/
```

I recover `yum` by this way.