# How can I install python3 by yum in AWS EC2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, dnf

I want to install pip3, python in my AWS EC2.
What I found how to install is

```
yum update
yum install gcc
yum install wget
yum install zlib-devel
cd _____
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.6.1.tgz
....
```

but when I write the first line It doesn't work.

```
# yum update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'
```

I don't know why the 'yum' doesn't work. how can i fix it?

Comment: I believe that yum is built with Python and this type of error suggests that your Python distribution or installed Python packages are broken. This might be fixable (I don't know) but one alternative option would be to launch a new, clean EC2 instance. Is that an option for you or is there too much on this EC2 instance to be able to rebuild it from scratch cleanly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DNF and YUM does not work after Purging usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303309/dnf-and-yum-does-not-work-after-purging-usr-lib-python3-5-site-packages)

Comment: @jarmod thanks to comment. I'm just start to learn EC2. so It's not that hard to relaunch.

Comment: @Lamanus the second answer In that link 'rpm -Va' is work for me. but next 'rpm --reinstall' is not work. it said 'rpm: no packages given for install'. I want to know how can I reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum install python36 (for python3.6)
sudo yum install python37 (for python3.7) and so on.